# Infinite representaion of an element in an infinte dimensional Hilbert space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $<e_n>$. Is it possible that every element of $H$ has a finite representation in terms of $e_n$'s? To be more specific does there always exist an element $x \in H$ such that $x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha_ne_n$ where infinitely many $\alpha_n$'s are non-zero.

Comment: Yes, for example $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e_n/n$.

Answer (score 1):

If every element is  has a finite expansion then $H$ becomes the union of $(M_n)_n$ where $M_n$ is the space spanned by $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$. But this contradicts Baire Category Theorem since each $M_n$ is closed with empty interior.

So, in every infite dimensaional Hilbert space, at least one element must have an infinite expansion in terms of $(e_n)$.